# Write custom function in Solr 5

Tags: solr

I am trying to upgrade SOLR 3 to 5 and we have a custom function based on this tutorial http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html
Unfortunately it seems really outdated for SOLR 5.

I did some replacements as below (omitted org.apache)
*solr.search.function.ValueSource* -> **lucene.queries.function.ValueSource** 
*solr.search.function.DocValues* -> **org.apache.lucene.queries.function.FunctionValues** 
*lucene.index.IndexReader* -> **lucene.index.LeafReaderContext** 
*lucene.search.Searcher* -> **lucene.search.IndexSearcher** 
*lucene.queryParser.ParseException* ->  **solr.search.SyntaxError**

Now I am able to compile the plugin but got exception (see log below) when I try to update document in SOLR. Any idea how to make it work?

```
2016-03-09 20:49:28.584 ERROR (qtp1450821318-14) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'services' is not available due to init failure: Error loading class 'solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler'
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1066)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:412)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
```

**[Update]**
Found the above error is actually my jar not loaded, which is put in server/solr/lib, not sure why as I already add `<str name="sharedLib">.lib</str>` in server/solr/solr.xml. Anyway, it's another issue, now I moved it to server/lib and loaded. However I got error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError like:

```
350825 ERROR (qtp434176574-15) [   ] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall An Error was wrapped in another exception - please report complete stacktrace on SOLR-6161
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'services' is not available due to init failure: org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1066)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:412)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:820)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:814)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.access$000(CoreContainer.java:87)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:467)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:458)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:542)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:489)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.createPlugin(PluginBag.java:121)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.init(PluginBag.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.core.PluginBag.init(PluginBag.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:765)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.search.ValueSourceParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, with the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` issue, I've found newer versions of Solr appear to sometimes sandbox custom code.

Loading from solrconfig.xml using a `<lib` directive gets round it. If you want to just bung your jar directly into Solr tho, you can also put it into `solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` - that gets the full path, whereas `server/solr/lib` does not.